# The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process using spreadsheet document

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel

Please help me to solve the problem, when i save the excel file throw this error i convert the excel file to zip file.

```
zip.Save(@"" + root + "/" + "" + userid + ".zip");
```

the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process 
my code is below

```
  using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(excelFilename, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
        {
             WriteExcelFile(ds, document);
        }

private static void WriteExcelFile(DataSet ds, SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet)
{
    spreadsheet.AddWorkbookPart();
    spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Workbook();

    spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Append(new BookViews(new WorkbookView()));

    //  If we don't add a "WorkbookStylesPart", OLEDB will refuse to connect to this .xlsx file !
    WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rIdStyles");
    Stylesheet stylesheet = new Stylesheet();
    workbookStylesPart.Stylesheet = stylesheet;

    //  Loop through each of the DataTables in our DataSet, and create a new Excel Worksheet for each.
    uint worksheetNumber = 1;
    foreach (DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
    {
        //  For each worksheet you want to create
        string workSheetID = "rId" + worksheetNumber.ToString();
        string worksheetName = dt.TableName;

        WorksheetPart newWorksheetPart = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet = new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Worksheet();

        // create sheet data
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.SheetData());

        // save worksheet
        WriteDataTableToExcelWorksheet(dt, newWorksheetPart);
        newWorksheetPart.Worksheet.Save();

        // create the worksheet to workbook relation
        if (worksheetNumber == 1)
            spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets());

        spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheets>().AppendChild(new DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet.Sheet()
        {
            Id = spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(newWorksheetPart),
            SheetId = (uint)worksheetNumber,
            Name = dt.TableName
        });

        worksheetNumber++;
    }

    spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
}
```

Comment: Well, is the file being used by another process?  Can you close that process?

Comment: How can i identify that process?? can u pls explain me

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have saved your document but you have not closed it. So, it will still be open with the **spreadsheetdocument** object.

Add the following line after you **save** the document.

```
spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Close();
```

If it doesn't help, kindly provide the full code so that we can look into it further. Good luck.

Comment: Did you try to close the document as explained above @MANIShanmugam

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not closing all your Workbooks before you try to put them in the Zip-File.
Put this at the end of the Method:

```
private static void WriteExcelFile(DataSet ds, SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheet)
{
...
spreadsheet.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Close();
}
```